# How to feed data into Multiple dense(2,)?

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, tensor

Model :

```
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense
from tensorflow.keras import Model

vgg_base =tf.keras.applications.VGG16(include_top=False, weights='imagenet')
x = vgg_base.output
x = tf.keras.layers.GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
cl1 = Dense(2, activation = 'softmax',name='cl1')(x)
cl2 = Dense(2, activation = 'softmax',name='cl2')(x)
model = Model(inputs=vgg_base.input, outputs= [cl1,cl2])
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='categorical_crossentropy'  , metrics=['categorical_accuracy'])
model.summary()
```

Here i have three Dense(2,) layers. I tried to feed data into model.fit() by using following custom data function

```
def func(img_batch, lb_batch):
  lbs = tf.one_hot(lb_batch,depth=2)
  return img_batch, lbs

train_Data = train_ds.map(func)

model.fit(train_Data,steps_per_epoch=400,validation_steps=40,
                    epochs=50,verbose=1))
```

But getting the following format
ValueError: Error when checking model target: the list of Numpy arrays that you are passing to your model is not the size the model expected. Expected to see 2 array(s), for inputs ['cl2', 'cl2'] but instead got the following list of 1 arrays: [<tf.Tensor 'args_1:0' shape=(None, 2, 2) dtype=float32>]...

Here the model is expecting a 2 separate arrays , but the custom funtion return single array with shape (2,2). So have to convert the single tf.Tensor array with shape(2,2) into 3 seperate tf.Tensor array .. How to solve this !

Model.summary() output :

```
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                    Output Shape         Param #     Connected to                     
==================================================================================================
input_1 (InputLayer)            [(None, None, None,  0                                            
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
block1_conv1 (Conv2D)           (None, None, None, 6 1792        input_1[0][0]                    
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
block1_conv2 (Conv2D)           (None, None, None, 6 36928       block1_conv1[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
block1_pool (MaxPooling2D)      (None, None, None, 6 0           block1_conv2[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
block2_conv1 (Conv2D)           (None, None, None, 1 73856       block1_pool[0][0]                
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
block2_conv2 (Conv2D)           (None, None, None, 1 147584      block2_conv1[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
block2_pool (MaxPooling2D)      (None, None, None, 1 0           block2_conv2[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
block3_conv1 (Conv2D)           (None, None, None, 2 295168      block2_pool[0][0]                
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
block3_conv2 (Conv2D)           (None, None, None, 2 590080      block3_conv1[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
block3_conv3 (Conv2D)           (None, None, None, 2 590080      block3_conv2[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
block3_pool (MaxPooling2D)      (None, None, None, 2 0           block3_conv3[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
block4_conv1 (Conv2D)           (None, None, None, 5 1180160     block3_pool[0][0]                
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
block4_conv2 (Conv2D)           (None, None, None, 5 2359808     block4_conv1[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
block4_conv3 (Conv2D)           (None, None, None, 5 2359808     block4_conv2[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
block4_pool (MaxPooling2D)      (None, None, None, 5 0           block4_conv3[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
block5_conv1 (Conv2D)           (None, None, None, 5 2359808     block4_pool[0][0]                
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
block5_conv2 (Conv2D)           (None, None, None, 5 2359808     block5_conv1[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
block5_conv3 (Conv2D)           (None, None, None, 5 2359808     block5_conv2[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
block5_pool (MaxPooling2D)      (None, None, None, 5 0           block5_conv3[0][0]               
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
global_average_pooling2d (Globa (None, 512)          0           block5_pool[0][0]                
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
cl1 (Dense)                     (None, 2)            1026        global_average_pooling2d[0][0]   
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
cl2 (Dense)                     (None, 2)            1026        global_average_pooling2d[0][0]   
==================================================================================================
Total params: 14,716,740
Trainable params: 14,716,740
Non-trainable params: 0
__________________________________________________________________________
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `tf.split` function to split the one tensor into three separate tensors.

```
img_batch_split = tf.split(img_batch, 3, axis = 1)
```

This will return a list containing three tensors of shape `(None, 1, 2)`. To get rid of the extra 1 dimension, you can use a `tf.squeeze`.

```
img_batch_split_squeezed = [tf.squeeze(x, axis = 1) for x in img_batch_split]
```

After this, each element in the list will be of dimension `(None, 2)`. Your entire function may look like this:

```
def func(img_batch, lb_batch):
  img_batch_split = tf.split(img_batch, 3, axis = 1)
  img_batch_split_squeezed = [tf.squeeze(x, axis = 1) for x in img_batch_split]

  lbs = tf.one_hot(lb_batch,depth=2)
  lbs_split = tf.split(lbs, 3, axis = 1)
  lbs_split_squeezed = [tf.squeeze(x, axis = 1) for x in lbs_split]

  return img_batch_split_squeezed, lbs_split_squeezed
```

Comment: img_batch_split is not required . Have to split the label alone. But still getting the same error

Comment: It would be helpful to post the code for creating your neural net as well, I don't know if I can give you further suggestions without that

Comment: I have updated the Model architecture which i  used.

Comment: Can you also include the output of the model.summary()

Comment: I have updated the model.summary() output int the question

Comment: Okay, is the error the exact same as what you received previously? If not, can you copy and paste error message directly?

Comment: ValueError: Error when checking model target: the list of Numpy arrays that you are passing to your model is not the size the model expected. Expected to see 2 array(s), for inputs ['cl2', 'cl2'] but instead got the following list of 1 arrays: [<tf.Tensor 'args_1:0' shape=(None, 2, 2) dtype=float32>]...

Comment: Sorry for all the questions. It seems like you are still passing 1 tensor to model.fit. Can you show the code that is creating this error?